# Create Json request for multiple products using angulajs

Tags: html, json, angularjs

We need to make JSON request for all the rows present in a table.

Table Structure

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ProductID</th>
                            <th>ProductName</th>
                            <th>ProductPrice</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
                            <td>{{product.ProductID }}</td>
                            <td>{{product.ProductName }}</td>
                            <td>{{product.ProductPrice }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

For single product we used below request which is working fine.

```
var request = {
                        "action": "valid",
                        "product":
                            {
                                "ProductID": $scope.ProductID,
                                "ProductName": $scope.ProductName,
                                "ProductPrice": $scope.ProductPrice
                            }
                        }
```

How to make request for multiple products

```
{
"message": "valid",
  "products": 
   [
                 {
                     "ProductID": $scope.ProductID,
                     "ProductName": $scope.ProductName,
                     "ProductPrice": $scope.ProductPrice
                 },
                 {
                     "ProductID": $scope.ProductID,
                     "ProductName": $scope.ProductName,
                      "ProductPrice": $scope.ProductPrice
                 }
   ]
}
```

Comment: why aren't you iterating over `$scope.products`?

Comment: This is simply rephrasing your [prior question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478040/how-to-make-json-format-of-all-table-rows-in-angularjs-to-call-webapi) and still doesn't clearly identify your problem or what exactly you are wanting to do. The array shown doesn't make sense as all items would have same values

Comment: @charlietfl : yoni lvey has understood it well. He also trying to give idea. See his comment

Comment: are you asking on how to put all the products into an *array* in your variable `request`?

Comment: yes, absolutely good understanding (y)

Comment: @Gaurav123 if people understand why are they asking questions? You really are over simplifying your statements and expecting people to figure out what they mean. Providing a proper written problem description will likely get you an answer in short time. If you already have an array it is not clear where the problem is in creating a different array or what exactly you need to do with it

Comment: @charlietfl : I understand your point of view and respect that too. Actually when I ask very short and compact questions then I have to give details so I am feeling that I have overexplained  my question. It should be compact and clear.

Comment: Well this is your second attempt to resolve the same problem and the issue is obviously not being expressed properly or you would have some answers already

Comment: No I didn't have any answer yet

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved now.

This is how I made Json request using angular.

```
validateProducts: function ($scope) {
            var jsonObj = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.products, function (data) {

                var rule = {};
                product["ID"] = product.ProductID;
                product["Name"] = product.ProductName;
                product["Price"] = product.ProductPrice;


                jsonObj.push(product);
            });
            $http({
                url: urlContent + '/api/ValidateProducts',
                method: "POST",
                data: { "Message": $scope.message, "Products": jsonObj }
            }).success(function (response) {
                $scope.products = response;
            });
        }
```